# Select two week old files, use first file's date as a starting point

Tags: powershell

I was wondering is there anyway to use first file's date (lastmodified) as a starting date and count -14 days from it? My aim is to choose all the files that are within that limit and list them in a text file. I can't sort files by date and choose folder's first files, because I have to do this for multiple files that have certain pattern in the same folder.

Comment: (Get-Date).AddDays(-14), this is how you can get the the date from 14 days ago. Now you can compare it with the lastmodified date. Note noone on SO will write you the whole script, make some research on your own, google is your friend

Comment: Thank you and my intention is not to leech of others but ask for tips for my problem. I'm still a beginner so I have sometimes problems on where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Note that FileInfo's LastWriteTime attribute is a [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7). There's AddDays() method, so let's use that. Like so,

```
$f = gci c:\temp\myTestFile.txt # Sample file
$twoWeeksAgo =$f.LastWriteTime.AddDays(-14) # Calculate a date from the past
gci C:\Temp\ | ? { # Get a list of files
    $_.LastWriteTime -ge $twoWeeksAgo # that have fresh enough last write time
}
```